# Java file lock in Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, file-io

File locking using java.nio package works fine with Windows OS but
same program is not working properly with Mac OS.

I am trying to delete the locked file in Windows where its not deleting the file.
But same thing i am trying to achieve in Mac OS where even though file is locked
or opened by FileWriter/FileOutputStream, its deleting the file.

Any suggestion for this issue ?
Is it bug in File lock implementation ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a bug (unless you call Windows a bug)

Locks are *advisory* on *nix systems. Nothing prevents you from deleting a locked file except checking to see if it's locked first.

In windows it's sort of the same, except the system commands check for locks and IIRC the default mode for opening a file is with an exclusive lock.